# How do i put the sender 's messages on the left and the receiver's messages on the right

Tags: java, android, xml

Right now i have this :

[image]

I have all my messages (the sender and the receiver's) on one side but i want them to be like your typical messaging app like Messenger or IMessage here is what i wanna achive :

[image]

This my adapter :

```
if(from_user.equals(current_user_id)){
        viewHolder.messageText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.message_back_other);
        viewHolder.messageText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }else{
        viewHolder.messageText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.message_back);
        viewHolder.messageText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);  
    }
```

and this is my xml for the message background :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
<corners android:radius="30dp"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use different xml layout files for the left and right side of the message list.

In my `Adapter` I check to see if I sent the message or received one:

```
        if(isMe) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_right, parent, false);
        }
        else{
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_left, parent, false);
        }
    }
```

Remove the views from the xml layout files that you do not need.

My xml layout file for the left:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDate"
        android:text="12/12/2017"
        android:textSize="@dimen/message_time_text_size"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="1dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/ride_message_time_color"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="Blank Message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/message_textview_left"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTime"
            android:text="11:00 PM"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/message_time_text_size"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/ride_message_time_color"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My xml layout file for right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDate"
        android:text="12/12/2017"
        android:textSize="@dimen/message_time_text_size"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="1dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/ride_message_time_color"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTime"
            android:text="12:30 PM"
            android:textSize="@dimen/message_time_text_size"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="1dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/ride_message_time_color"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:text="Blank Message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/message_textview_right"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Novel ::  Have you had the chance to try the solution?

Comment: Sorry for the late response ahah just tried your method and it worked thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use different item types for messages from the sender vs recipient. That will let you set both background color, text color, and gravity for each in different layouts.

Comment: please explain more aha i'm new to android